# What are my options for timing?

Tags: c#, time, timer, xna

I'm making a TextBox control in XNA and do not have access to the `GameTime` class. Currently I am trying to simulate the blinking text cursor caret and have successfully done so using this code:

```
int deltaTickCount = Environment.TickCount - previousTickCount;

if (deltaTickCount < CursorBlinkRate && Selected)
{
    spriteBatch.Draw(emptyPixel, new Rectangle(caretLocation, Rectangle.Y + 1, caretWidth, caretHeight), Color.Black);
}
else if (deltaTickCount > CursorBlinkRate * 2)
{
    previousTickCount = Environment.TickCount;
}
```

However, I'm a bit wary of using `Environment.TickCount`. If the computer was running long enough, wouldn't the program eventually crash or produce unpredictable behavior when the tick count exceeded its integral size?

Does anyone know what Windows does? I imagine it would use the system clock. Would that be a more suitable solution? I imagine they used something like total milliseconds in to the second instead of the tick count, but I'm not sure.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally use the system diagnostics timer in a lot of situations.

It's a pretty powerful tool which creates a timer for you with a lot of good controls.

```
using System.Diagnostics;

Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
```

Then use inbuilt controls:

```
timer.Start();
if(timer.elapsedMilliseconds() > ...)
{ }
timer.Reset();
```

etc...

This would allow you to reset the timer?

Answer (score 1):

When Evnironment.TickCount rolls over, deltaTickCount will end up being negative, so you know it has happened.  The calculation then becomes:

```
if (deltaTickCount < 0)
   deltaTickCount = int.MaxValue - previousTickCount + Environment.TickCount;
```

Answer (score 0):

Without bothering with what would happen in the case of an integer overflow, simply change to:

```
int deltaTickCount = 
    Environment.TickCount > previousTickCount 
      ? Environment.TickCount - previousTickCount 
      : CursorBlinkRate * 3;
```